# Sharing Travis configuration among multiple repositories

Tags: github, travis-ci

We develop some custom elements using `polymer`. Each element lives in a separated repository under one organization. All of them has the same Travis config file so that would be logical to define and edit it in one place.

Is there any way to setup only one `.travis.yml` file for all repositories under specific organization?

Is there some way to specify some default Travis config for an organization?

Couldn't find any information about the topic in the Travis docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mechanism for this (that I'm aware of) provided by the travis service itself. I've 'solved' this by scripting the update of the `.travis.yml` in my family of modules from a template in a higher-level repository.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-config-imports

(still in beta though)